# Interaction between web site and native app

Tags: javascript, android

I'm not so experienced in Android development, but I have some research to do.

I need to develop a HTML+CSS+JavaScript website that has to interact with a 3rd party app.

I understood that I can do this with a native app using a `WebView` and wrapping the communications with the app with the method `addJavascriptInterface`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29 .

Is it possible to do the same only with JavaScript?

Thank you

Comment: You're trying to do what exactly? Are you trying to trigger some function in your Android application by a JavaScript function?

Comment: I've an android back-end app that can interact with other apps. I would like to do the front end app just as a web site without the webview layer.